# invalid database install path. - Appcelerator Ttianium

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

im new to appcelerator titanium. im trying to install a database but i couldn't.

i have tried the following codes,

```
    Ti.Database.install('myDB.sqlite', 'myDB');
    var db = Ti.Database.open('myDB');

    var db = Titanium.Database.install('myDB.db','myDB');

    var db = Titanium.Database.install('myDB.sqlite','myDB');
```

but it shows the error -

```
invalid database install path. /Users/wintech/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/E1DC3E24-7BA6-4A69-94B7-87256846F500/Sample.app/myDB.sqlite  in -[TiDatabaseProxy install:name:] (TiDatabaseProxy.m:120)
```

please help me friends!!

Comment: it worked.. but i got the error while inserting a record

Ti.Database.install('myDB.sqlite','myDB');

var db = Ti.Database.open('myDB');

db.execute('INSERT INTO test (t_Id, t_Name) VALUES (1,"sam")');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just over the good tutorial series:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-database-driven-tables-with-sqlite/

You will find many tutorials of Titanium.

Cheers!

Comment: i tried that tutorial only.. i have tried with database extension .db and .sqlite. but the file is not generated in application with the extension .sql.

Comment: Try with this: var db = Ti.Database.install('../products.sqlite','products'); Please check with database path.

Comment: its worked out... i have used 'Titanium' insteed if 'Ti'. i dono what make the difference.